# It is possible to set the high of the cinnamon bottom panel to 40 px?

Tags: 12.04, cinnamon

Changing the value in an cinammon theme doesn't work correctly. I use cinnamon 1.4 (ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the newest unstable version from ppa solves the problem.